# How to write induction proof of Sprague-Grundy function for subtration game?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

So lets say that S={1,2,3}
I find the sequence of Sprague-Grundy function. 
How do I justify my answer using induction?

Answer (score 0):

The proof of the Sprague-Grundy theorem is available at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem#Proof . I'm not sure what a subtraction game is, but if it's an impartial game, then it falls under the Sprague-Grundy theorem.